# Sorting month columns in pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataset made up of 4 columns, a numerator denominator, country, and month. I am pivoting it to get months as columns, country as index, and values as `sum(numerator)/sum(denominator)`. The only problem I get is that my columns are all out of order. How can I sort the columns so earlier months appear first? I tried `table = table.sort_index(1)` with no luck.

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Numerator', 'Denominator'], index='Country',
                columns=['Month'], aggfunc=np.sum)

table = table['Numerator'] / table['Denominator']
```

*Edit with full example and data*:

Data:

```
Denominator,Numerator,Country,Month
10,4,USA,1-Jan
6,2,USA,1-Jan
10,1,Canada,1-Jan
9,2,Canada,1-Jan
6,4,Canada,1-Feb
4,3,Canada,1-Feb
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Numerator', 'Denominator'], index='Country',
                columns=['Month'], aggfunc=np.sum)
table = table['Numerator'] / table['Denominator']
print table
```

Output:

```
Month    1-Feb     1-Jan
Country                 
Canada     0.7  0.157895
USA        NaN  0.37500
```

Desired Output:

```
Month    1-Jan     1-Feb
Country                 
Canada     0.157895  0.7
USA        0.37500   NaN
```

Comment: Is the month column a string or integer? Can you show 5-10 rows of the original `df` so your output may be reconstructed?

Comment: Before you show the data , I can only provide this link for you ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe/47152692#47152692

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. It's a string. I've added data as well as the full code.

Comment: Are the recordings made in chronological order?

Comment: in the csv? Not necessarily

Comment: @user2242044 uh, then this is not going to be so easy... let me get back to you.

Comment: would it not be easiest to just sort before pivoting the data?

Comment: @user2242044 Yes... see edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
*Impose sorting order for `pivot`, before `pivot`*
This option works because `pivot` automatically sorts index and column values and displays them. Currently, `Month` is a string, so sorting will be done lexicographically. You can change this by a datetime conversion.

```
df.Month = (pd.to_datetime(df.Month, format='%d-%b'))
```

```
table = pd.pivot_table(
   df, 
   values=['Numerator', 'Denominator'], 
   index='Country',
   columns=['Month'], 
   aggfunc=np.sum
)
table = table['Numerator'] / table['Denominator']

table.columns = table.columns.strftime('%d-%b')
```

```
table

           01-Jan  01-Feb
Country                  
Canada   0.157895     0.7
USA      0.375000     NaN
```

---

**Option 2**
*Reorder after `pivot`*
If your data is stored in chronological order, you can just find `df.Month.unique` and use it to reindex your result.

```
table.reindex(columns=df.Month.unique())

Month       1-Jan  1-Feb
Country                 
Canada   0.157895    0.7
USA      0.375000    NaN
```

If that isn't the case (and your data *isn't* chronologically ordered), here's a little workaround using `pd.to_datetime` + `pd.Series.argsort` + `unique`.

```
u = df.Month.iloc[
       pd.to_datetime(df.Month, format='%d-%b').argsort()
].unique()

table.reindex(columns=u)

Month       1-Jan  1-Feb
Country                 
Canada   0.157895    0.7
USA      0.375000    NaN
```