# How to sort columns except index column in a data frame in python after pivot

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, indexing, pivot-table

So I have a data frame

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame({"loc" : ["ab12","bc12","cd12","ab12","bc13","cd12"], "months" : 
         ["Jun21","Jun21","July21","July21","Aug21","Aug21"], "dept" : 
         ["dep1","dep2","dep3","dep2","dep1","dep3"], "count": [15, 16, 15, 92, 90, 2]})
```

That looks like this:

[image]

When I pivot it,

```
df =  pd.pivot_table(testdf, values = ['count'], index = ['loc','dept'], columns = ['months'], aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df
```

it looks like this:

[image]

I am looking for a sort function which will sort only the months columns in sequence and not the first 2 columns i.e loc & dept.

when I try this:

```
df.sort_values(by = ['Jun21'],ascending = False, inplace = True, axis = 1, ignore_index=True)[2:]
```

it gives me error.

I want the columns to be in sequence Jun21, Jul21, Aug21

I am looking for something which will make it dynamic and I wont need to manually change the sequence when the month changes.

Any hint will be really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting month columns in pandas pivot\_table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429439/sorting-month-columns-in-pandas-pivot-table)

Comment: Check my answer @Ruchika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start by converting the column `months` in `datetime` like so :

```py
>>> testdf.months = (pd.to_datetime(testdf.months, format="%b%y", errors='coerce'))
>>> testdf
    loc     months      dept    count
0   ab12    2021-06-01  dep1    15
1   bc12    2021-06-01  dep2    16
2   cd12    2021-07-01  dep3    15
3   ab12    2021-07-01  dep2    92
4   bc13    2021-08-01  dep1    90
5   cd12    2021-08-01  dep3    2
```

Then, we apply your code to get the `pivot` :

```py
>>> df =  pd.pivot_table(testdf, values = ['count'], index = ['loc','dept'], columns = ['months'], aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()
>>> df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
>>> df
months  NaT     NaT     2021-06-01  2021-07-01  2021-08-01
0       ab12    dep1    15.0        NaN         NaN
1       ab12    dep2    NaN         92.0        NaN
2       bc12    dep2    16.0        NaN         NaN
3       bc13    dep1    NaN         NaN         90.0
4       cd12    dep3    NaN         15.0        2.0
```

And to finish we can reformat the column names using `strftime` to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%b%y') if pd.notnull(t) else '')
>>> df
months                  Jun21   Jul21   Aug21
0       ab12    dep1    15.0    NaN     NaN
1       ab12    dep2    NaN     92.0    NaN
2       bc12    dep2    16.0    NaN     NaN
3       bc13    dep1    NaN     NaN     90.0
4       cd12    dep3    NaN     15.0    2.0
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. That was a typo. I have it like Jul21 only. But the problem here is that, this solution only renames the columns and does not sort the entire column. like values of Aug are getting assigned to Jun.

Comment: Ah ok, It was the most challenging part to solve my friend. Does the rest of the answer solved your question ? If so, please don't hesitate to validate the answer and upvote it ;)

Comment: Oh you are right ! I will look at it !

Comment: I updated the answer, now it conserves the correct data associated to the columns as expected !

Comment: Thank You! Yes, I think this will work. I am still on it, now it is giving me an error "AttributeError:  'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'"

Comment: I just try it again from start to end with the data you provided and I have no error or warning. Can you give me more context in order to help you ?

Comment: I imagine that in your real data, you can have some missing dates, I added the `errors='coerce'` parameter during the conversion to `datetime`, this should solve the  `"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'` error.

Comment: Hi @tlentali, thank you for this. even though this one worked for me later; in my code I have used df = df.sort_index(axis = 'columns', level = 'months', ascending = False) and then assigning the column names and then rearranging them again for loc & dept columns. Because sort_index also moved loc & dept columns to the right

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple if you do using groupby

```
df = testdf.groupby(['loc', 'dept', 'months']).sum().unstack(level=2)
df = df.reindex(['Jun21', 'July21', 'Aug21'], axis=1, level=1)
```

Output

```
          count             
months    Jun21 July21 Aug21
loc  dept                   
ab12 dep1  15.0    NaN   NaN
     dep2   NaN   92.0   NaN
bc12 dep2  16.0    NaN   NaN
bc13 dep1   NaN    NaN  90.0
cd12 dep3   NaN   15.0   2.0
```